# How to edit ExpandableContentTemplate in Blend

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik, windows-phone, expression-blend

I'm using Telerik RadExpanderControl in my Wp8 app. I open the project in Blend, right-click the *RadExpanderControl* under *Objects and Timeline*, select *Edit Additional Templates*. Here my options are *Edit Generated Content (ContentTemplate)*, *Edit AnimatedIndicatorContentTemplate* and *Edit ExpandedStateContentTemplate*.

None of these actually provide me access to the *ExpandableContentTemplate* which is what I need.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, is isn't available as an extractable template. However you can do this to create one:

```
 <telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="24, 4, 4, 4" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
                Text="{Binding TextYouWantToBind}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
```

A workaround that I do when I need to use Blend to style the ExpandableContentTemplate is to style the DataTemplate of the (Generated)ContentTemplate to my liking, then copy paste it into the DataTemplate of the ExpandablecontentTemplate.

I have reported this to the windows Phone Team